# Is it possible to disable the delete cross in input-text field via CSS?

Tags: css, input

Is it possible to disable the delete cross in the input-text field via CSS?

I have a currency sign on the right and want to avoid that it will be overlapped onfocus.

```html
<input type="text" value="100000" />
<span style="margin-left:-1.5em">&#8364;</span>
```

Comment: What do you mean by delete cross?

Comment: @Mukyuu See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add padding-right for the input field. By setting padding-right property, the currency value and the input value won't get overlapped.

codepen: https://codepen.io/bearnithi/pen/MLOBmG

```
<input type="text" style="padding-right: 20px" value="100000" />
<span style="margin-left:-1.5em">&#8364;</span>
```

To remove cross symbols from input filed in IE browsers, use the following CSS

```
/* To remove cross symbol in input field  */
input::-ms-clear {
   display: none;
}
```